# Update and Insert Statement in one Control

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

My problem is after inserting a data in database the no. of copies in tblBooklist isn't subtrated by one. Here's my sample codes:

```
      Dim sqlinsert As String
      sqlinsert = "UPDATE tblBookList SET Copy = Copy - 1 WHERE 
      [Accession Number] = @Accession_Number"
      sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO tblBookIssue([Accession Number],[Book Title],
      [Student Name],[Years],[Section],[Date Issue],[Time],[Am or Pm],[Date to be Return], 
      [Status])  VALUES (@Accession_Number,@Book_Title,@Student_Name,@Years,
      @Section,@Date_Issue,@Time,@Am_or_Pm,@Date_to_be_Return,@Status)"

      Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(sqlinsert, con)
      cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Accession_Number", txtBookAccessNumber.Text))
      cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Book_Title", txtBookBookTitle.Text))
      cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Student_Name", txtBookStudentName.Text))
      cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Years", txtBookYears.Text))
      cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Section", txtBookSection.Text))
      cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Date_Issue", Label88.Text))
      cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Time", lblTime.Text))
      cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Am_or_Pm", lblAm.Text))
      cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Date_to_be_Return", 
      txtBookDatetobeReturn.Text))
      cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Status", lblStatus.Text))
      con.Open()
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

      MessageBox.Show("Book has been borrowed", "Issue", MessageBoxButtons.OK, 
      MessageBoxIcon.Information)
```

Thank you for your help in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Update statement is never executed, first thing you do is set sqlinsert to your Update statement, next thing you do is overwrite it with your Insert statement which you then execute.

Comment: Not an access / vb programmer so I'd probably have got the syntax wrong if I'd posted any code :-)

Answer (score 1):

As already pointed out by OTTA, here is the corrected code:

```
  Dim sqlinsert As String
  sqlinsert = "UPDATE tblBookList SET Copy = Copy - 1 WHERE 
  [Accession Number] = @Accession_Number"
  Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(sqlinsert, con)
  cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Accession_Number", txtBookAccessNumber.Text))
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

  sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO tblBookIssue([Accession Number],[Book Title],
  [Student Name],[Years],[Section],[Date Issue],[Time],[Am or Pm],[Date to be Return], 
  [Status])  VALUES (@Accession_Number,@Book_Title,@Student_Name,@Years,
  @Section,@Date_Issue,@Time,@Am_or_Pm,@Date_to_be_Return,@Status)"
  cmd.CommandText = sqlinsert
  cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Book_Title", txtBookBookTitle.Text))
  cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Student_Name", txtBookStudentName.Text))
  cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Years", txtBookYears.Text))
  cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Section", txtBookSection.Text))
  cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Date_Issue", Label88.Text))
  cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Time", lblTime.Text))
  cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Am_or_Pm", lblAm.Text))
  cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Date_to_be_Return", 
  txtBookDatetobeReturn.Text))
  cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@Status", lblStatus.Text))
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

  MessageBox.Show("Book has been borrowed", "Issue", MessageBoxButtons.OK, 
  MessageBoxIcon.Information)
```